# Like/Dislike in rails via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

i'd like to make a like/dislike ability on my RoR application. How can i make it via Ajax-requests ?

dislike and like - are integer how can i make an Ajax-request, than i can send the data of what i want to increment either "like" or "dislike" counter in my methods

I have a table with posts :

```
#app/views/dashboard/view.html.erb
<table>
  <%if @post.count!=0%>
    <%@post.each do |p|%>
      <%if !p.text.nil?%>
      <tr>
       <td><b class="margin"><h4><%=p.text%></b></h4></td>
       <td>by <%=p.user.username%>&nbsp;&nbsp; </td>
       <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up likeAction"><%= link_to p.like, dashboard_like_path, :remote => true, :id => 'likecount' %> </td>
       <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"><%= link_to p.dislike, dashboard_dislike_path, :remote => true, :id => 'dislikecount' %> </td>
      <%end%>
    <% end %>
  <%else%>
    There's no posts yet, but you can add <%=link_to "one", dashboard_posts_create_a_post_path%>
  <%end%>
</table>
```

My js file

```
#app/views/dashboard/view.js
$('#likecount').text(@post.like);
$('#dislikecount').text(@post.dislike);
```

my methods in controller :

```
      #app/controller/dahsboard_controller.rb  
      def like
        @post.increment!(:like)
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html
          format.js
        end
      end

      def dislike
        @post.increment!(:dislike)
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html
          format.js
        end
      end
```

My dashboard.js in assets/javascripts

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $("likeAction").click(function(){
     $.ajax({
        url: dashboard_like_path,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(){
            $('#linkcount').text(data);
        }
        error: function(error){
           alert(error);
        }
     });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have Rails built-in AJAX functionality, so no need for calling $.ajax. Simply set `remote: true` on your `link_to 'Like', ..., remote: true` and respond with the same code you have in `app/views/dashboard/view.js`: `format.js { render action: 'view' }`

**EDIT**: As long as like and dislike are set as member routes on posts:

```
                              dislike_post POST   /posts/:id/dislike(.:format)                                             posts#dislike
                                 like_post POST   /posts/:id/like(.:format)                                                posts#like
```

You will have a params[:id] (if you send one) to do something like `@post = Post.find(params[:id])`, if you share this code with show, like and dislike. You can create a `set_post` before filter, so you don't repeat yourself.

Comment: i get an error, that i get a nil file in my method ? how can i send my post variable into this method ?

Comment: @post being nil? Just get if from the params[:id], just like you do on show: `@post = Post.find(params[:id])` Like and dislike should be member routes, so they have :id on them

Comment: How do i get id from @post if params[:id] contains id from the current logged in user ?

Comment: `params[:id]` has whaterver you pass, `dislike_post_path(post)` will send the post.id as `params[:id]`. Let us see your routes for those two actions, I cannot infer them from `<%= link_to p.like, dashboard_like_path, :remote => true, :id => 'likecount' %>`

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to look at a gem called [`acts_as_votable`](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable)

This sets much of your model functionality up - allowing you to use the likes of `@post.downvote_from @user2` etc. I'll let you look into that, as it's what you need in the backend I think.

---

In regards the front-end (especially Ajax), you'll have to set up a controller action, and then hit it with a JS request:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :posts do
   match :vote, via: [:post,:delete]
end

#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :js, :html, only: :vote

   def vote
      if request.delete?
         #downvote
      elsif request.post?
         #upvote
      end
   end
end
```

This will allow you to use the following:

```
#app/views/posts/vote.js.erb
$(".element").html("<%=j render partial: "post/vote_count", object: @post %>");

#app/views/posts/index.html.erb
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
   <%= render partial: "post/vote_count", object: :post %>
<% end %>

#app/views/posts/_vote_count.html.erb
<% method = @post.liked_by(current_user)
<%= link_to post.likes, post_vote_path(post), method: :post, remote: true %>
```

--

The Ajax functionality is pre-built into Rails; you have to be wary of which controller action it's going to send you to, as well as the response given.

My above code uses the [`respond_to`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_to) block to invoke the `.js.erb` response -- allowing you to perform some actions when you send your request.

Comment: Thanks, i appreciate your advice, but how can i resolve my problem using my code(just correcting it)?